# Celery queue for actions on other websites

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

Hey I have a problem and need some advice for it. I did some research but did not found anything, which describes my exactly problem.

The process I want to develop:

1. Many users can trigger actions, which add some entries in to my queue (RabbitMQ)
2. The queue task should fetch login and password (from the database [could be many accounts]) for a website and performing some actions. Those actions are returning some kind of result and saved in the database together with the used account.
3. Another scheduled task (every 5 minutes) should fetch the saved database entries and login on the website again and perform some other actions.

The problem: Every login/password combination can only be logged in at the same time. If a combination is used more than once at the same time the tasks are going to logout each other.

What I thought until now:

1. Create an own queue for each login/password combination and have a worker for it which processes only one entry at the same time.
2. Lock rows in the database

Do you have any suggestions or solutions for this problem?

My used frameworks are: Django as the main application framework, Celery+RabbitMQ for my queue system.

**Edit1:**
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time
Maybe this article could help me.. Maybe setting a cachekey could help. But if all login/password combinations are "blocked" the task will run into some deadlock problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of locking.

If you can tolerate occasional failures then you could do a quick and dirty distributed locking using something like memcached or redis. Or, as you say, your database.

I don't know if I'd even bother locking rows in the database - personally I'd use Redis and just create a mapping

```
www.whatever.com:username:hash(password) -> worker hostname:worker pid:start time
```

then your workers can check if a particular combination of website/username/password is locked.

Using flower you can also check if the worker that has locked a particular set of credentials is still active.

Wrap your tasks in a try/except/finally block to ensure that the lock is released at the end of each task even if it fails

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis()

class MyTask(Task):
    __call__(site, username, password):
       key = '%s:%s:%s' % (site, username, hash(password) 
       val = '%s:%s:%s' % (datetime.now().isoformat(), self.request.hostname, os.getpid())

       if not setnx(key, val):
           LOG.error('%s locked', key)
           return

        try:
            return super(MyTask, self).__call__(site, username, password)
        finally:
            r.del(key)
```